# Using Selenium to capture certain Target

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm still a bit new to the Selenium IDE so I don't know much on locating different ways to target a specific value. Below are some codes that I want Selenium to click on but I'm having a hard time working it.

I tried using //span[contains(text(),'Test Case Creation & Approval')] but it gives me an error that it was not found.

**This is when I do not hover on the class**

```
<span class="dijitTreeLabel" data-dojo-attach-event="onfocus:_onLabelFocus" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="treeitem" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" aria-expanded="false">Test Case Creation & Approval</span>
```

**This is when I do hover on the class**

```
<span class="dijitTreeLabel dijitTreeLabelHover" data-dojo-attach-event="onfocus:_onLabelFocus" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="treeitem" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" aria-expanded="false">Test Case Creation & Approval</span>
```

Comment: try these `//span[@class="dijitTreeLabel"]`, `//span[@class="dijitTreeLabel dijitTreeLabelHover"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath seems to be right. Add wait for element presence. 
You could also try the following ways:
//span[contains(.,'Test Case Creation & Approval')] 
//*[contains(text(),'Test Case Creation & Approval')]

If both doesn't work, add a breakpoint at the page and check how many nodes it detects with this xpath. If it's more than one, you'll have to make some changes to the locator.

Comment: Thanks, I also added a wait/pause in between and that worked as well.